# sql insert database android studio cannot run successfully

Tags: java, android, sql

i just complete my homework given but it not working...
for our android project..
[here the picture of an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rGta.png)
i tried search in youtube how to make sql insert. it doesn't work.
just like this

**myactivity**

import android. os.Bundle
    import android. support. v7. app. AppCompatActivity
    import android. view. View
    import android. widget. Button
    import android. widget. EditText
    import android. widget. Toast

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DataBaseHelper myDb;
EditText getname, getusername,getpassword;
Button signin;
String name,username, password;
Boolean result;
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE="com.example.studentpc.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
      signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signinbtn);
    signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Clickme();
        }
    });

}
private void Clickme(){
    myDb = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    getname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editname);
    getusername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editusername);
    getpassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpassword);

    name = getname.getText().toString();
    username = getusername.getText().toString();
    password = getpassword.getText().toString();
    result= myDb.insertData(name,username,password);
    if (result.equals(true)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Signin 
 Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Signin Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

**databasehelper**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Student_table";
long result;
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "USERNAME";
public static final String COL_4 = "PASSWORD";
public DataBaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTERGER 
KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD PASSOWRD)");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
}
public boolean insertData(String name, String username, String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,username);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,password);
    result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
 if (result==-1){
return false;
}else {
return true;
}
}
}
```

it says cannot run the app/ app has been stop

Comment: Seems like your app has crashed. Please post the stacktrace of the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you have written:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTERGER 
KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD PASSOWRD)");
```

There are plenty of mistakes. I have corrected some, which I could notice.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER 
KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD PASSWORD)");
```

Also, I don't think PASSWORD is a data type. For passwords, generally text type is used.

P.S. : Use Room persistence library, if you can.

Comment: Tnx by the way.